“Gtk is reporting wrong mouse position y inside a widget” on Linux while CursorLockMode.Locked
I have a problem. I’m making an FPS Controller. I have a script that turns the camera up and down and the body of the character left and right.
When I rotate the camera up and down, i have lags (>110 ms) and errors appear in the console:
“Gtk is reporting wrong mouse position y inside a widget”.
This happens almost every second.
I use ubuntu 22.04 with xfce 4.18.
    void Start()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    Vector3 MoveDirection{
        get{
            return new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"),0,Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate(){
        Walk();
        Rotate();
    }

    void Rotate(){
        xRotation -= Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y");

        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -70f, 70f);

        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"));

        MechaCamera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
    }

    void Walk(){
        _rb.AddRelativeForce(MoveDirection * WalkSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

I was recommended to use the new Input System and borderless fullscreen mode, but this did not affect the solution of the problem in any way.
